# OS X Ventura TypeError: libmemcached does not support SASL

Tags: python, memcached, sasl, pylibmc

I'm using Flask_Caching 2.0.1 in a Flask app, which uses pylibmc, which uses libmemcached 1.0.18_2 on OS X Ventura 13.0.1. Either the libmemcached that comes standard or using `brew install libmemcached` doesn't seem to support SASL. Here is the relevant part of the error message:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_caching/backends/memcache.py", line 123, in factory
    return cls(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_caching/backends/memcache.py", line 107, in __init__
    self._client = pylibmc.Client(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pylibmc/client.py", line 142, in __init__
    super().__init__(servers=translate_server_specs(servers),
TypeError: libmemcached does not support SASL
```

I tried building from source, and hit tons of errors that others overcame but I could not (like here: [How can I install libmemcached for Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10 in order to install the memcached.so PHP extension on Mamp 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27004144/how-can-i-install-libmemcached-for-mac-os-x-yosemite-10-10-in-order-to-install-t)).

Has anyone run into and overcome this issue? Is there a flag or process that can enable SASL support in libmemcached either using Homebrew or other? All relevant SO responses are from 2016 and earlier it seems and did not work for me.

Comment: I should say, this works fine on my 2013 Mac with older versions of all libraries. It also works fine on a Ubuntu machine. The problem seems to be isolated to the most recent library versions, Homebrew or OS X Ventura.

Comment: Specifically, pylibmc 1.5.2 works. So the question is how to get pylibmc 1.6.3 to use SASL?